# How to fix 'Keyerror : 0 # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality' , in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

i'm trying to implement logistic regression but when i try access a location , it gives me a keyerror :0

i m tryin this on jupyter notebook, 
the data file contains 3 columns sep by commas

```
import numpy as np
path = "Downloads//machine-learning-ex2//ex2//ex2data1.txt"
df= pd.read_csv(path,header=None)
headers=["Exam 1 Score","Exam 2 Score","Admit/Reject"]
df.columns=headers
x=df.iloc[:,:-1] 
y=df.iloc[:,2]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mask= y==1
->adm=plt.scatter(x[mask][0].values,x[mask][1].values)
not_adm=plt.scatter(x[~mask][0].values,x[~mask][1].values)
plt.xlabel('Exam score 1')
plt.ylabel('Exam score 2')
plt.legend((adm,not_adm),('admitted','not admitted'))
plt.show()
```

i expect it to show me a plot of x[i][0] and x[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q39OG.png) ,but it gives me an error

Comment: Ok i got it , its because it was trying to plot the 'headers' too, as soon as i took headers down . it plotted .. i m going to keep this post up for future reference

Answer (score 1):

its because it was trying to plot the 'headers' too, as soon as i took headers down , it plotted as expected ..
Thank you for viewing my question